# Inherit unit test from parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, multiple-inheritance

I would like to write some test in a way that are executed for all classes that inherit from a Parent.

For example I have the class motor with two specializations:

```
class Motor():

    def run(self, energy):
        pass


class ElectricMotor(Motor):

    def run(self, electric_energy):
        heat = electric_energy * 0.99
        motion = electric_energy * 0.01
        return heat, motion

class DieselMotor(Motor):

    def run(self, diesel_energy):
        heat = diesel_energy * 0.65
        motion = diesel_energy * 0.35
        return heat, motion
```

Then I have two tests which apply to every kind of motor:

```
class MotorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_energy_should_be_conserved():

        for class_instance in all_motor_child_classes:
            energy=10
            assert sum(class_instance.run(energy))==energy
            energy=20
            assert sum(class_instance.run(energy))==energy

    def test_motors_should_produce_heat():

        for class_instance in all_motor_child_classes:
            energy = 10
            heat, motion=class_instance.run(energy)
            assert heat>0
```

What I'm looking for is a way to do the loop

```
for class_instance in all_motor_child_classes:
```

or a different programming pattern to obtain the same result.

Any idea?
Thanks
Riccardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two points here: first having a list of `Motor` child classes, then having an instance of each of those classes.

The stupid simple solution is to maintain those lists in your testcase's `setUp` :

```
from motors import ElectricMotor, DieselMotor

class MotorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    _MOTOR_CHILD_CLASSES = [ElectricMotor, DieselMotor]

    def setUp(self):
       self.motor_child_instances = [cls() for cls in self._MOTOR_CHILD_CLASSES]

    def test_energy_should_be_conserved():
        for class_instance in self.motor_child_instances:
            self.assertEqual(sum(class_instance.run(10)), 10)
            # etc
```

If your `Motor` subclasses `__init__()` expect different arguments (which they shouldn't if you want to have [proper subtyping according to liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - but well, "practicality beats purity"), you can add those arguments to your `MOTOR_CHILD_CLASSES` list:

```
   # (cls, args, kw) tuples
    _MOTOR_CHILD_CLASSES = [
       (ElectricMotor, (42,), {"battery":"ioncad"}),
       (DieselMotor, (), {"cylinders":6}),
       ]
```

and use them in the `setUp()`:

```
       self.motor_child_instances = [
           cls(*args, **kw) for cls, args, kw in self._MOTOR_CHILD_CLASSES
       ]
```

For something more "automagic", you can use a custom metaclass on `Motor` so it can registers its subclasses and provide a list of them, but then you'll loose the ability to provide per-class arguments - and you'll also make your tests code much less readable and predicable.

Now another - and IMHO **much** better - approach is to use inheritance in your tests instead: define a mixin object with all the tests that are common to all `Motor` child classes :

```
class MotorTestMixin(object):

    # must be combined with a unittest.TestCase that
    # defines `self.instance` as a `Motor` subclass instance

    def test_energy_should_be_conserved(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum(self.instance.run(10)), 10)

    def test_should_produce_heat(self):
        heat, motion = self.instance.run(10)
        self.assertGreater(heat, 0)
```

then have one TestCase per subclass:

```
class DieselMotorTest(MotorTestMixin, TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = DieselMotor()


class ElectricMotorTest(MotorTestMixin, TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = ElectricMotor()
```

One of the benefits of this approach (the others being simplicity, readability, and a much better error reporting on failed tests - you'll immediatly know which subclass failed without having anything special to do) is that you don't have to touch your existing code when you add a new `Motor` subclass - you just need to add a new individual TestCase for it -, and you can even do so in a distinct module, following the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).